python custom exception not being caught
I have created an exception like this
class MyException(Exception):
    """
    myexception
    """

and then the code is like :
 try:
        _, _, test = test_str.rpartition("/")
        return test
    except MyException:
        print(
            f'An error occurred while transforming')
    return test_str

When the code is executed with test_str = None, the exception is not caught. If I replace MyException with Exception, it works as expected. What's the issue ?
If I replace MyException with Exception, it works as expected.

Where is the code that raises a MyException as opposed to an Exception?

None.rpartition will raise an AttributeError. AttributeError is a subclass of Exception, so except Exception will catch it.
AttributeError is not a subclass of MyException, so except MyException will not catch it.
Defining a new exception provides some method with something new to raise, in order to more accurately describe a problem it encounters. It does not provide you with a new way to describe a different exception already raised by a method.

Since None.rpartition('/') will raise AttributeError exception, you can raise your exception like this:
try:
    _, _, test = test_str.rpartition("/")
    return test
except AttributeError as e:
    raise MyException(f'An error occurred while transforming: {str(e)}')

return test_str

Other option is to check if test_str is not a valid string before rpartition call:
if not isinstance(test_str, str):
    raise MyException(f'test_str should be a string')

_, _, test = test_str.rpartition("/")
return test

